# How to generate feathersjs primus client without starting the server

Tags: feathersjs

I use below code to generate `featherjs-primus` client js file. But the `primus function` is not called until I call `app.listen()`. Is there a way for me to generate this file without start the server?

```
app
  .configure(primus({
    transformer: 'websockets',
    timeout: false
  }, (primus) => {
    const lib = primus.library();
    primus.save(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/primus.test.js'));
  }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [app.setup](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/readme.html#setup) instead of `app.listen` to run that callback. The websocket providers will however need an HTTP server passed to `app.setup`. More information can be found in the [middleware chapter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/middleware/mounting.html).

Comment: I am looking for a way for client side to generate the featherjs client js file by setting up the same configuration as server side. Is it possible for that?

Comment: You can see the Primus configuration used by `feathers-primus` in https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-primus/blob/master/src/index.js#L23. You should be able to use that and generate the file that way.

Comment: I found out that in order to call `app.setup` I have to create a http server. All http server instance is created from ***.listen() method which means I need to launch a server listening on a port number. Is there a way to call `app.setup` without a live http server? Or whether I can create a http server instance without starting it?

Comment: I updated my answer using the code I linked for how to create the same Primus library code that `feathers-primus` code.